# Lower compiled dependencies downloaded when adding google-cloud-pubsub version 1.107.0 in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, google-cloud-pubsub

When I add the below dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>1.107.0</version>
</dependency>
```

compiled dependencies like `com.google.api.grpc » proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1` should be downloaded in 1.89.0 (refer https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub/1.107.0).

But in my repository, when I am adding this dependency those compiled dependencies are downloaded with lower versions e.g: `com.google.api.grpc » proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1` downloaded in 1.41.0.

Why this is happening? And what should be done to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably grabbed from some other time of your dependency tree.

You can check that with `mvn dependency:tree`.

To fix a transitive version, put an entry into `<dependencyManagement>`.